# Create unordered list from custom field type entires separated by a comma

Tags: custom-post-types, php

I have a custom field type set up and need a way for a client to add a list of links that I can then output as a UL with each being an LI. I am hoping they can enter a comma separated list in the input and I can output the list with php where each value in between the commas can be separated out.[image]

or maybe it can be done if they put each link on a new line? Or maybe there is a better way to tackle this, it's my first attempt at using/creating custom post types.

Comment: Using a custom field plugin, you could more easily define the type of content they can enter into each box. ACF has a nice "repeater" field type that will let you add as few or as many items as you need, and an "url" field type that requires them to enter a URL. This would ensure they enter properly formatted links and prevent issues with commas, semicolons, etc. if you have a somewhat less tech-savvy user or just someone who is prone to typos.

Comment: Are those options on the premium version of ACF? I'm using the free one.

Comment: Yes, repeater is premium. Not sure on URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should be pretty straight forward:

```
$rawcontent = get_field("myfield");
$rawcontent = preg_replace("!</?p[^>]*>!", "", $rawcontent); // remove <p>
$all_links = preg_split("/\s*,\s*/", $rawcontent);
foreach($all_links as $link) {
    if(!trim($link)) continue;
    print "<li>$link</li>";
}
```

A comma certainly would work, but note that this would break if you had commas inside the link text (`<a href="...">hello, world</a>`).
You could easily alter the `preg_split` line to split on other things, though, like line breaks (`\n`). I'm not sure what the ACF editor inserts when you just press enter, but I'm sure that you can split it.

Comment: That created a <li></li> but it's empty

Comment: That's why you should run the code you post here ;) Sorry, I had a typo, `$rawcontent` vs `$raw_content`. See the edited version, or fix it in your code.

Comment: @janh is that correct for new lines? `/\n*,\n*/`

Comment: <?php
    $rawcontent = get_field('resources');
    $all_links = preg_split("/(\n)/", $rawcontent);
      foreach($all_links as $link) {
         print "<li><a href='$link'></a></li>";
     }
    ?>

Comment: I used $all_links = preg_split("/(\n)/", $rawcontent); with a new line start and that seemed to do the trick. The problem I'm facing now is because I am adding them in a wysiwyg editor it is wrapping each entry in a <p> tag so my output is showing up like <li><a href="<p>www.mylink1.com</p>"><a/> and there is a blank <li> at the end.

Comment: Yes, that should work if there are real line breaks between the links. If it doesn't work, you'll have to look at what `$rawcontent` actually contains to see where you can split.

Comment: I've added a regexp to remove all `<p>` tags (and their closing parts), and it should now skip over empty elements, so no more `<li></li>` without content.

Comment: @jahn thank you, that got rid of the <p> tags, I am still getting a a blank <li> at the end. The output is: <li><a href='&nbsp;'>&nbsp;</a></li>

Comment: You have an invisible link at the end of your input. It's probably best to remove it there, but you can of course use another regexp as well: `$rawcontent = preg_replace("!<a[^>]*>(&nbsp;|\s*)</a>!", "", $rawcontent);` should remove any links that only contain a "non breaking space" entity, or contain nothing but whitespace.